# using ng-switch and ng-repeat for a slider

Tags: angularjs, slider, angularjs-animation, ng-switch

I can't make this [kind of slider](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch) work, taking data from the controller.

This example works fine:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="SliderCtrl">
    <div class="panel-body"  ng-switch="selectedSlide">
        <img  src="img0.jpg" ng-switch-when="0" class="my-switch-animation" />
        <img  src="img1.jpg" ng-switch-when="1" class="my-switch-animation" />
        <img  src="img2.jpg" ng-switch-when="2" class="my-switch-animation" />
        <img  src="img3.jpg" ng-switch-when="3" class="my-switch-animation" />
        <img  src="img4.jpg" ng-switch-when="4" class="my-switch-animation" />
        <img  src="img5.jpg" ng-switch-when="5" class="my-switch-animation" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But if I change the img tag for a `ng-repeat` which should result in the same code, it doesn't work.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="SliderCtrl">
    <div class="panel-body"  ng-switch="selectedSlide">
        <img  ng-repeat="slide in slides" src="{{ slide.img }}" ng-switch-when="{{ slide.id }}" class="my-switch-animation" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-switch-when` doesn't support expression so I'd suggest you to use `ng-if` work same as like `ng-switch-when`

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="SliderCtrl">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <img  ng-repeat="slide in slides" src="{{ slide.img }}" ng-if="slide.id == selectedSlide" class="my-switch-animation" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[Related Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/09uGsU3Y27tnwYvfeyPl?p=preview) Without images

Answer (score 0):

If value of slides is correct its should work check the example I have create here http://jsfiddle.net/tRxzr/636/

```
function Ctrl() {
this.slides = [
    {src: 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/pic_angular.jpg'}, 
    {src: 'http://www.ocpsoft.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/angularjs.png'}];
```

};

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your example is not using ng-repeat inside ng-switch directive